# GridCacheTxManager assertion

Tags: gridgain

Why does Gridgain cache TX manager throw assertion error in case of invalid commit (error in my own store)

Exception ok, but why assertion?

ver. platform-os-6.1.6

Thanks

```
java.lang.AssertionError
at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.cache.GridCacheTxManager.addRolledbackTx(GridCacheTxManager.java:969)
at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.cache.GridCacheTxManager.addRolledbackTx(GridCacheTxManager.java:936)
at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.cache.GridCacheTxManager.rollbackTx(GridCacheTxManager.java:1211)
at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.cache.GridCacheTxLocalAdapter.userRollback(GridCacheTxLocalAdapter.java:952)
at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridDhtTxLocalAdapter.finish(GridDhtTxLocalAdapter.java:784)
at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.colocated.GridDhtColocatedTxLocal.rollbackAsync(GridDhtColocatedTxLocal.java:471)
at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridDhtTxLocalAdapter.rollback(GridDhtTxLocalAdapter.java:838)
at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.cache.GridCacheTxAdapter.close(GridCacheTxAdapter.java:758)
at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.endTx(GridCacheAdapter.java:3628)
at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.cache.GridCacheTxProxyImpl.close(GridCacheTxProxyImpl.java:188)
```

Comment: Can you provide more details on how you start your transaction and what kind of exception is thrown from your store?

Comment: Exception was Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint (by my mistake)

Comment: This issue will be fixed in the upcoming 6.2.1 release.